# Managed Package Released Type

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, package-install, release

When I click on Upload button in Managed Package It's asking Release Type, **Managed- Released** and **Managed -Beta**

[image]

In Managed - Released they have mentioned  **Note: you will not be able to edit some properties after release.** not sure What are all the properties.

Tried by viewing **tell me more**  link in the note, Still not able to find What are all the properties.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=uploading_packages.htm&type=5

Can anyone please guide me what are the Properties will not able to edit.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant documentation reference is the ISVforce Guide, under [Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm). It covers most metadata types and explains the manageability rules that will be applied after you ship a component in a managed-released package.

As a general rule, any attribute called out as "Developer Editable" can be changed by you and shipped in an upgrade to subscriber orgs. Anything called out as "Subscriber and Developer Editable" can be changed by you, but can also be changed by subscribers in their own org, and therefore cannot be shipped in an upgrade by you.

Shipping a managed package is a kind of social contract (enforced by the platform) between you and your subscribers. The platform will prevent you from making a wide variety of changes that could potentially break subscribers' orgs. As a consequence, you should generally not upload a managed-released package until you are sure you are ready to ship.

**If you aren't sure what you are doing, and are not shipping to customers, use a beta package**, but note that you should almost never install a beta package in a persistent org. Beta packages cannot be upgraded, so to upgrade an org from a beta to a later version, you must completely uninstall the beta package. Beta packages should only be installed in scratch orgs and in sandboxes you don't mind refreshing.

Comment: An important addition -- sometimes it is possible to install a beta package package at a trial org of salesforce. That would lead to a required package removal and re-installation with manual data migration.